# Testing for null in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code in a loop

```
   NSArray * images = [definitionDict objectForKey:@"Images"];
    NSLog(@"images in definitionDict %@", images);
    if (!images )
        NSLog(@"NULL");
    else
        NSLog(@"NOTNULL");
```

which gives the following outputs

```
images in definitionDict (
    "/some/brol/brol.jpg"
)
NOTNULL
images in definitionDict <null>
NOTNULL
```

I do not understand the second case, where the images array is null. Why is this not detected correctly in my test ? How can I debug such a problem ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`<null>` is not `nil`. `nil` will print `(null)` when printed. What you have is an `NSNull`. `NSNull` IS an object, it just doesn't respond to much. Its available as a placeholder for you to use.

To test for `NSNull` you can use `if ([images isEqual:[NSNull null]])`

See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on `NSNull`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print out the memory address of an Objective-C object, or any other pointer, you should use the flag `%p` not `%@`. The flag `%@`, expects a string.

However if the argument isn't a string, `NSLog` will automatically call `-description` on the passed object. And when the method returns an `NSNull`object, the `-description`on that object returns the string `<null>`

```
NSObject *o = nil;
NSLog(@"%p", o);
```

**Output:** `0x00000000`

```
NSObject *o = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%p", o);
[o release];
```

**Output:** something like `0x12345678`

Mind:

```
NSNull *n = [NSNull null];
NSLog(@"%p", n);
```

**Output:** a memory address that always will be the same, but will differ from `0x00000000`

The correct way to test if their are objects in the array is like this.

```
NSArray *myArray = [someObject array];
if([myArray isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    NSLog(@"No objects");
} else {
    NSLog(@"%d objects.", (int)[myArray length];
}
```

Comment: Your solution at the bottom will crash in this situation. This isn't an array that contains no objects. It's an NSNull, and NSNull doesn't respond to length.

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg I edited it. It still seems like a mystery why Apple created an `NSNull` class. And especially why would one set an NSNull object in an `NSDictionary`. If you just wouldn't define the key, then the method would still return `nil`.

Comment: In this case, you need to be able to distinguish having no object, verses having a null object. `nil` is just zero, it is also returning if the key doesn't exist. So here, I'd imagine after parsing some JSON into a dictionary which had a JSON `null` in it, an `NSNull` was created.